# Image on comminity login page

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder

I am editing a community login page. I want to change the image which was used in the 'Rich Content Editor'. This component is retired. So we are editing the HTML version of it. [image]
Here is the code of it.

```
<div class="header-wrapper"> 
 <div style=" margin:auto"> 
  <img class="nabef-logo" src="/NABEF_Logo_White-569342.png" /> 
  <div class="help-text">
    Help?  | 
   <a class="color-white" href="mailto:*****@*****">***@***</a> 
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div> 
<p style="margin:auto;"><img class="sfdcCbImage" src="/NABEFregistration_1200x350b-153502.jpg" /></p>
```

In the above code, there is an image in the src tag. in that there is an image "/NABEF_Logo_White-569342.png". But I am not getting where it is added or from where it is fetched.
How to find this image?
Is there any alternative way to add this image?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your images as a static resources and then show them in communities following this method answered here:

[How to include images from static resources in lightning components used in communities?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115772/how-to-include-images-from-static-resources-in-lightning-components-used-in-comm/115784)